# Syntax error flask application

Tags: python, multithreading

I have following code:

`t1 = threading.Thread(target = app.run, args = (host='0.0.0.0', port = 443))`

and it gives me an error:

```
File "/home/deploy/tgbot/tgbot.py", line 1170
t1 = threading.Thread(target = app.run, args = (host='0.0.0.0', port = 443))
                                                    ^
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequential arguments for `app.run` can be passed in a tuple (constructed with parentheses, but no names). The named arguments must be passed in a dictionary. Dictionaries are constructed with `dict()` or curly braces, not parentheses.

Since `host` and `port` are the first two arguments to `app.run`, any of the following should work:

```
# positional args, passed as a tuple
t1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run, args=('0.0.0.0', 443))

# named args, passed in a dictionary created via dict()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run, kwargs=dict(host='0.0.0.0', port=443))

# named args, passed in a dictionary created via {}
t1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={'host': '0.0.0.0', 'port': 443}))
```